# is it possible to run TDM64-GCC compiler to run with code::blocks

Tags: gcc, codeblocks, tdm-mingw

I am trying to build 64 bit applications using 64bit TDM-GCC and Code::Blocks IDE.
What I am unable to configure is the combination of the compiler and IDE.

I have looked at the IDE wiki and TDM wiki; but haven't got details I need.

Is there a straight forward way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible because I've personally done it myself, and used that development configuration for the better part of a year before finally moving on from Code::Blocks to Codelite (they're similar IDEs, but Codelite is more Obj-C friendly out of the box).

To setup Code::Blocks, all you have to do is go into the build settings and point the compiler bin location to your TDM-GCC bin folder. I think the only other thing you need to do is make sure Code::Blocks attempts to run `mingw32-make.exe` instead of `make.exe`, which it looks for by default. This is in the same setup window. All the other programs run by Code::Blocks should already have the correct name.

If you're still having trouble, can you post the exact compiler output when you try and build?

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot and comment again. I think I had trouble figuring out the options to set the compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Code::Blocks 64 bit on Windows 10 64 bit OS

Try this:

Put the TDM-GCC 64 bit version in the directory (drive) you're using for Code::Blocks. 
I have both under C:/ (which is normal unless you using another drive). Open CB and click on the TDM in CB (Management window Left side).

Now go to **Settings>Compiler>Tool Chain** executables tab and click on Auto-detect in the compiler Install dir.  You may want to put a check mark in some of boxes below. 
**AFTER THAT MAKE SURE TO SAVE** all the changes before you close CB.  Good Luck.